# Difference between the execution sequence of two outputs of perror function in C

Tags: c, execution, errno

[Difference between output sequence on the same code on removing "\n"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCwTT.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("GeeksForGeeks", "/root/C");
printf("Value of error no : %d\n", errno);
printf("The error message is : %s\n", strerror(errno));
perror("Message from perror.");
return 0;
}
```

This is my code but when I remove the "\n", the sequence of execution of perror changes.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Also, you can not rely on `errno` remaining unchanged if you call a library function.  Per [C11 **7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`**, p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3): "The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  `printf()` does not set `errno` on error, so `printf()` is free to change the value of errno to any non-zero value it wants.

Comment: Please, do not use screenshots to show the output of your program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, `stdout` is in linebuffered mode so it flushes on `\n`, and `perror` writes to `stderr`.

Adding `fflush(stdout);` before the `perror` call will fix it.